# How to print separate rows and convert to string?

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

**Python 3.2:**

I have list which has lists inside and it looks like this:

```
list = [['o', 'o', 'o'], ['o', 'o', 'o'], ['o', 'o', 'o']]
```

I would like to print it like this:

```
ooo
ooo
ooo
```

How can I do that? I used this method already to print list on separate rows:

```
print(*list, sep = "\n")
```

It looks like this:

```
['o', 'o', 'o']
['o', 'o', 'o']
['o', 'o', 'o']
```

How to convert those rows to string?

Answer (score 1):

Using [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), you can convert a list of strings into a string:

```
>>> ''.join(['o', 'o', 'o'])
'ooo'
```

---

```
lst = [['o', 'o', 'o'], ['o', 'o', 'o'], ['o', 'o', 'o']]
for row in lst:
    print(''.join(row))
```

SIDE NOTE: Avoid using `list` as a variable name. It shadows builtin type/function name [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list).

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [['o', 'o', 'o'], ['o', 'o', 'o'], ['o', 'o', 'o']]
for s in (''.join(i) for i in l):
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
for a in l:
    print(*a, sep='')
```

Or:

```
print(*(''.join(a) for a in l), sep='\n')
```